# which word is more suitable in the context? coherent, inline, match

Tags: word-usage

I have received two tables from my colleague. In one table the values are in metric unit (m). In the other table I am supposed to have same values but in the imperial unit (ft). Unfortunately the values were not converted correctly . I want to tell it to my colleague in an  formal email. How can I say it in English?
The values in these two tables are not coherent.
The values in these two tables are inline.
The values in these two tables does not match.
cheers

Answer (score 2):

The values **do not match**, or the values **are not equivalent**.

Coherent implies that something doesn't make sense or doesn't fit together. In this case, the tables make sense, as in you can tell what they're supposed to mean, but they are wrong. It would not be natural to use coherent here. The tables would not be coherent if, for instance, your colleague converted from meters to oranges.

Inline means that something is literally inline, like "this is an inline quote" as opposed to

> This quote is taken out of the paragraph.

You can say that something is incorrect by saying it is "out of line", but confusingly enough, in English "out of line" generally refers to inappropriate behavior, and not something that is literally misaligned.